# How to implement sql query in yii2 search model?

Tags: yii2, yii2-advanced-app

I have following query:

```
      SELECT hs.*FROM hire_screening hs 
      INNER JOIN (SELECT resume_id,MAX(created_date) AS MaxDateTime 
      FROM hire_screening GROUP BY resume_id) hire_screening 
      ON hs.resume_id = hire_screening.resume_id 
      AND hs.created_date = hire_screening.MaxDateTime
```

I tried this:

```
   $query = HireScreening::find()
           ->select(["hs.resume_id","MAX(hs.created_date) AS MaxDateTime"])
           ->innerJoin('hire_screening as hs','hs.resume_id = hire_screening.resume_id')

          ->where(['hire_screening.created_date' => 'MaxDateTime'])
          ->orderBy(['(hs.created_date)' => SORT_DESC])
          ->groupBy(['hs.resume_id']);
```

When I use group by the result shows the first values of each 'resume_id' in the order that stored in the table. I just need the most latest distinct resume_id 's according to created_date. 
How can I implement this query in yii2 search model? Please help.

Comment: Please update question with code u have tried at this point. See [How to ask](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) article to improve your question. Remember that Stack Overflow is not your personal online query converter.

Comment: Am sorry. Am a beginner in Yii2. So please excuse any mistake. Question is updated.

Answer (score 1):

If you want to execute the raw sql query means, then you can use 
createCommand function. But it will return the array so in grid you should use array data provider.

```
$array= Yii::$app->db->createCommand("
      SELECT hs.*FROM hire_screening hs 
      INNER JOIN (SELECT resume_id,MAX(created_date) AS MaxDateTime 
      FROM hire_screening GROUP BY resume_id) hire_screening 
      ON hs.resume_id = hire_screening.resume_id 
      AND hs.created_date = hire_screening.MaxDateTime")->queryAll();
```